# Как правильно написать через классы структуру сильно ветвящегося дерева?

Tags: c#, дерево

Написать сильно ветвящееся дерево на основе бинарного дерева c двумя типами ссылок.(на узел брата и и на узел потомка), соответствующие структуре музыкальной коллекции, хранящейся на пк.

Есть главный каталог музыки, в нем располагаются подкаталоги и/или файлы с музыкальными композициями , каждый каталог может хранить как подкаталоги так и файлы (вложенность подкаталогов  не ограничена)

Каталог задается только своим название, а про файлы с музыкальной композицией дополнительно известна ее длительность (в секундах)

Данные вводятся с клавиатуры: для нового каталога запрашивается его название и название существующего в дереве родительского каталога, для файла доп. запрашивается его длительность

Изначально в дереве существует корневой каталог с названием "Музыка"

Можно считать, что названия всех каталогов коллекции уникальны

Упорядочивать по алфавиту содержимое каталогов не нужно

Comment: Чем сильно ветвящееся дерево отличается от несильно ветвящегося?

Comment: @aepot, скорее всего тем, что в не сильно ветвящемся, ссылки на дочерние узлы непосредственно в полях хранятся, типа `left`, `right` - а с сильно ветвящимся - количество дочерних узлов заранее неизвестно :)

Comment: @Grundy то есть список узлов - это бинарное дерево? Тогда в чем смысл такого ветвящегося дерева?

Comment: @aepot несильно ветвящиеся , я так понимаю это вы имеете ввиду бинарное дерево? Просто в сильно ветвящемся у нода может быть произвольное количество детей

Comment: @aepot по сути это тоже Б-дерево, только без балансировки

Answer (score 0):

Вышло как-то так

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class SvTreeNode
    {
        public readonly string Name;
        protected SvTreeNode(string nameOfNode)
        {
            Name = nameOfNode;
        }
    }

    public class Track : SvTreeNode
    {
        
        public readonly int DurationInSecond;

        public Track(string name, int durationInSecond) : base(name)
        {
            DurationInSecond = durationInSecond;
        }
    }

    public class Folder : SvTreeNode
    {
        public readonly List<SvTreeNode> ListOfFileInFolder = new List<SvTreeNode>();
        public Folder(string name) : base(name){}
    }
    
    
}
```

////

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class SvTree
    {
        private readonly Folder _root;

        private int _count; 
        
        public SvTree(string nameOfRoot)
        {
            _root = new Folder(nameOfRoot);
            _count++;
        }

        private SvTreeNode Search(string name)
        {
            return SearchTo(name, _root);
        }
        private SvTreeNode SearchTo(string name, Folder folder)
        {
            if (name == _root.Name) return _root;
            
            foreach (var file in folder.ListOfFileInFolder)
            {
                if (file.Name == name) return file;
                
                if (file is Folder tempFile) 
                    SearchTo(name, tempFile);
            }

            return null;
        }

        
        
        private static void InsertTo(Folder folder, SvTreeNode node)
        {
            folder.ListOfFileInFolder.Add(node);
        }
        public void InsertFolder(string nameOfNewFolder, string nameOfFolder)
        {
            var insertValue = new Folder(nameOfNewFolder);
            _count++;
            
            if (Search(nameOfFolder) is Folder currentFolder) 
                InsertTo(currentFolder, insertValue);
        }
        public void InsertMusicFile(string nameOfMusicFile, int durationInSec, string nameOfFolder)
        {
            var insertValue = new Track(nameOfMusicFile, durationInSec);
            _count++;
            
            if (Search(nameOfFolder) is Folder currentFolder) 
                InsertTo(currentFolder, insertValue);
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

///

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            const string nameOfRootFolder = "Музыка";
            
            var music = new SvTree(nameOfRootFolder);
            
            //Альбом Convolk "AntiHero"
            music.InsertFolder("ANTIHERO", nameOfRootFolder);
            music.InsertMusicFile("convolk - swear to god",129, "ANTIHERO");
            music.InsertMusicFile("convolk - black sheap",164, "ANTIHERO");
            music.InsertMusicFile("convolk - medicine",156, "ANTIHERO");
            
            //Альбом Незабудки "1999"
            music.InsertFolder("1999", nameOfRootFolder);
            music.InsertMusicFile("НЕЗАБУДКИ - Бегство",177, "1999");
            music.InsertMusicFile("convolk - Балкон",183, "1999");
            music.InsertMusicFile("convolk - Лето",160, "1999");

            Console.WriteLine();

            
            
        }
    }
}
```